# Cannot read property 'championships' of undefined with Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a tournament object in a view, when I print with:

```
{{ tournament.championships | json }}
```

I have:

```
[
        {
            "id": 24,
            "tournament_id": 1,
            "category_id": 2,
            "created_at": "2018-12-30 09:22:49",
            "updated_at": "2018-12-30 09:22:49",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "users": [],
            "teams": [],
            "category": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Junior Team",
                "gender": "X",
                "isTeam": 1,
                "ageCategory": 5,
                "ageMin": 13,
                "ageMax": 15,
                "gradeCategory": 0,
                "gradeMin": 0,
                "gradeMax": 0,
                "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:01",
                "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:01"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "tournament_id": 1,
            "category_id": 6,
            "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:01",
            "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:01",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": 48,
                    "slug": "qferry-at-daughertynet",
                    "name": "Conner Robel",
                    "firstname": "Carson",
                    "lastname": "O'Kon",
                    "email": "qferry@daugherty.net",
                    "role_id": 5,
                    "federation_id": 36,
                    "association_id": 14,
                    "club_id": null,
                    "grade_id": 4,
                    "city": "Schimmelshire",
                    "latitude": 55.358721,
                    "longitude": -147.124799,
                    "country_id": 484,
                    "gender": null,
                    "avatar": null,
                    "verified": 1,
                    "token": "Wvm4mTZmgBwPENx4ZTq74SKBQyGdbi",
                    "provider": "created",
                    "provider_id": "qferry@daugherty.net",
                    "locale": "es",
                    "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09",
                    "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09",
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "pivot": {
                        "championship_id": 3,
                        "user_id": 48,
                        "confirmed": 1,
                        "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09",
                        "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 49,
                    "slug": "pjast-at-gmailcom",
                    "name": "Mr. Walton Schiller",
                    "firstname": "Irving",
                    "lastname": "Cronin",
                    "email": "pjast@gmail.com",
                    "role_id": 5,
                    "federation_id": 36,
                    "association_id": 14,
                    "club_id": null,
                    "grade_id": 1,
                    "city": "Vivianberg",
                    "latitude": -0.428004,
                    "longitude": -118.03927,
                    "country_id": 484,
                    "gender": null,
                    "avatar": null,
                    "verified": 1,
                    "token": "z2WAEgONLfoYMpVcaSWbXQJboqAIuZ",
                    "provider": "created",
                    "provider_id": "pjast@gmail.com",
                    "locale": "en",
                    "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09",
                    "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09",
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "pivot": {
                        "championship_id": 3,
                        "user_id": 49,
                        "confirmed": 1,
                        "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09",
                        "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 65,
                    "slug": "ygerhold-at-gmailcom",
                    "name": "Prof. Vickie Collins",
                    "firstname": "Earnestine",
                    "lastname": "Donnelly",
                    "email": "ygerhold@gmail.com",
                    "role_id": 5,
                    "federation_id": 36,
                    "association_id": 14,
                    "club_id": null,
                    "grade_id": 5,
                    "city": "Doraside",
                    "latitude": -22.741194,
                    "longitude": -47.782872,
                    "country_id": 484,
                    "gender": null,
                    "avatar": null,
                    "verified": 1,
                    "token": "IonUEGfGeyaIf6GhiVxtoJQj45h0Nj",
                    "provider": "created",
                    "provider_id": "ygerhold@gmail.com",
                    "locale": "es",
                    "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09",
                    "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09",
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "pivot": {
                        "championship_id": 3,
                        "user_id": 65,
                        "confirmed": 1,
                        "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:10",
                        "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:10"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 66,
                    "slug": "cummingsafton-at-legrosnet",
                    "name": "Mrs. Lori Wehner PhD",
                    "firstname": "Hermina",
                    "lastname": "Price",
                    "email": "cummings.afton@legros.net",
                    "role_id": 5,
                    "federation_id": 36,
                    "association_id": 14,
                    "club_id": null,
                    "grade_id": 5,
                    "city": "East Wilbert",
                    "latitude": 62.899588,
                    "longitude": 50.771194,
                    "country_id": 484,
                    "gender": null,
                    "avatar": null,
                    "verified": 1,
                    "token": "fBJIGFnyH54L1SByCByWjPMShAdNhr",
                    "provider": "created",
                    "provider_id": "cummings.afton@legros.net",
                    "locale": "en",
                    "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09",
                    "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09",
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "pivot": {
                        "championship_id": 3,
                        "user_id": 66,
                        "confirmed": 1,
                        "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:10",
                        "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:10"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 67,
                    "slug": "niko03-at-yahoocom",
                    "name": "London Skiles Jr.",
                    "firstname": "Erica",
                    "lastname": "Hintz",
                    "email": "niko03@yahoo.com",
                    "role_id": 5,
                    "federation_id": 36,
                    "association_id": 14,
                    "club_id": null,
                    "grade_id": 4,
                    "city": "Kuphalhaven",
                    "latitude": 85.654199,
                    "longitude": -150.132582,
                    "country_id": 484,
                    "gender": null,
                    "avatar": null,
                    "verified": 1,
                    "token": "pdJpvkhnxbEQLUCM5JVjWB6c3HkvqJ",
                    "provider": "created",
                    "provider_id": "niko03@yahoo.com",
                    "locale": "en",
                    "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09",
                    "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09",
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "pivot": {
                        "championship_id": 3,
                        "user_id": 67,
                        "confirmed": 1,
                        "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:10",
                        "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:10"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 68,
                    "slug": "mayercurtis-at-yahoocom",
                    "name": "Novella Hoeger II",
                    "firstname": "Tad",
                    "lastname": "Macejkovic",
                    "email": "mayer.curtis@yahoo.com",
                    "role_id": 5,
                    "federation_id": 36,
                    "association_id": 14,
                    "club_id": null,
                    "grade_id": 2,
                    "city": "East Alba",
                    "latitude": -51.71245,
                    "longitude": -104.271828,
                    "country_id": 484,
                    "gender": null,
                    "avatar": null,
                    "verified": 1,
                    "token": "ScBVBqCr4jdg1h7Z53ahTRCSabveoU",
                    "provider": "created",
                    "provider_id": "mayer.curtis@yahoo.com",
                    "locale": "es",
                    "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09",
                    "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:09",
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "pivot": {
                        "championship_id": 3,
                        "user_id": 68,
                        "confirmed": 1,
                        "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:10",
                        "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:10"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "teams": [],
            "category": {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Women's Team",
                "gender": "F",
                "isTeam": 1,
                "ageCategory": 5,
                "ageMin": 18,
                "ageMax": 0,
                "gradeCategory": 0,
                "gradeMin": 0,
                "gradeMax": 0,
                "created_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:01",
                "updated_at": "2018-12-11 09:41:01"
            }
        }
    ]
```

So, data seems to be OK.

But when I try to loop on it with:

```
<div *ngFor="let championship of tournament.championships; let i = index" class="card mb-4">
```

I'm getting:

```
CompetitorsComponent.html:5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'championships' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (CompetitorsComponent.html:5)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:10750)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10147)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10388)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:10351)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10148)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10388)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10330)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10153)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10388)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:10351)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10148)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10388)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10330)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10153)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11040)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:10718)
    at ViewRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:8534)
    at core.js:4411
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ApplicationRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick (core.js:4411)
    at core.js:4303
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3654)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at NgZone.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run (core.js:3568)
    at Object.next (core.js:4303)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:3385)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:195)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:133)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at EventEmitter.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next (Subject.js:47)
    at EventEmitter.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit (core.js:3377)
    at checkStable (core.js:3623)
    at Object.onHasTask (core.js:3667)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask (zone.js:441)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount (zone.js:461)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount (zone.js:285)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:205)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
```

I don't understand why, objects seem to be OK...

Why tournament is evaluated as undefined ? I explicitly print it in view, and it is not undefined.

Any idea?

Comment: Where are you looping through it? Your question indicates that your were about to post some code... then didn't.

Comment: use `tournament?.championships` if you get the value from http request

Comment: How do you load your json file? Show us the `tournament` variable in your component

Comment: Have you parsing the json to JS object before assigning to tournament variable ?

Comment: @prettyfly I'm looping in my view with : `<div *ngFor="let championship of tournament?.championships; let i =index">``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading the information from an HTTP request, it's likely not resolved by the time you go to loop over it (presumably with `*ngFor`), so, to mitigate, you can do one of two things.

You can wrap the whole render block in an `*ngIf="tournament"`, so it only attempts the loop after it's resolved.

e.g

```
<div *ngIf="tournaments">
     <div *ngFor="let championship of tournament.championships">
           ...
     </div>
</div>
```

Or, you can use the safe navigation operator

```
 <div *ngFor="let championship of tournament?.championships">
      ...
 </div>
```

Whichever is preferable for your own flavour of readability.

Comment: you've forget the `?` :)

Comment: Yes, I did. Well... I didn't. I wrote `tournaments` first time round, but then deleted the `s` when I realised it wasn't plural. Guess I deleted the `?` instead of the `s`.. because I deffo edited twice!  Good spot nonetheless! 

Answer (score 0):

if you declare any property even if you set the type of it , the initial value is `undefined` and try to access to  sub proprty `tournament.championships` of the value you will get an common javascript error

```
 Cannot read property 'championships' of undefined
```

in that case you use **safe navigation operator**

```
{{tournament?.championships | json}}
```

try this way if you use ngFor  and the `tournaments` value is result of http request

```
<ng-container *ngIf="tournaments">
       <div *ngFor="let championship of tournaments.championships">
           ...
     </div>
</ng-container>
```

*finally*

in case of `ngFor` an easy solution is to set `tournaments` to empty object `tournaments={}`